# How bad is it to use a molly in a stud?

Tags: drywall, drywall-anchor

Unfortunately, I started installing a [blind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_blind) before properly reading up about drywall and studs (my previous flats did not feature drywalls). I ended up drilling a hole into the stud and fastening the blind using [mollies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molly_(fastener)).

I tried to pull the mollies out, but they seemed to be anchored quite well. I hate to leave a sloppy job behind me, but I would have it even more if I made a bigger damage.

How bad is it to put mollies into studs? Should I replace the mollies with plastic screw anchors?

Comment: I don't think those mollies are really ever intended to be removed. Also, plastic screw in anchors would not attach into a stud (properly even if you managed). Why not just use long wood/drywall screws into the wood, and abandon anchor all together?

Comment: Not sure I transmitted the right question. In essence, I made a mistake in the past. Is it worth fixing it? I will, of course, use long wood screws into the wood next time.

Comment: Your question still isn't clear. Are you asking about the performance of your installation, or about the legal or moral implications of leaving the anchors behind when you move?

Comment: I think this is one of those few situations where you just have to ask 2 questions "Will it stay?" and "Will anyone notice until they take it apart?", and if the answer is "Yes" and "No" respectively, why do the work a second time?

Comment: Mollies are tough to remove. I will unscrew them until the screw is almost out then press in this flexes the metal 3 or 4 cycles of doing this the back side breaks off and then the front can be pulled out. After pulling the front  out a little dab of sheet rock mud or Spackle to fill the hole and it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the molly/anchor, that you used, is holding securely - you should be fine.

Anchors similar to that pictured below, that "fill" the hole - NOT the tapered ones - are ideal in situations, like yours. Tapered mollies, are designed to expand, into compressible mediums. The anchor pictured, "is" compressible, and grips uniformly, along its length - normally intended for harder materials like; wood, tile, concrete, etc. The ridges, along its length, ensure that it grips, and does not turn, while driving in the screw.

The two types are generally not interchangeable.

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to regain the screw to wood interface - just glue a wooden dowel, into the hole; cut it short enough to be below the drywall surface; spackle the drywall; and then drive your screw into the dowel.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are you did not drill a 1 1/2" hole for a molly (into a stud, such that you created a notch), so the rules about notching are not really applicable, but this would be the best kind of guide.

The depth for notching a stud depends on whether or not it is load bearing. For a load bearing stud you can notch up to 25% (7/8") depth; for a non-load bearing stud it is 40% (roughly 1 3/8") depth.

Now, considering how deeply you drilled and the size of the bit should help elucidate the answer. If you drill bit was less than 3/8", then you should be okay. If the drill bit was more like 3/4" and you drilled more than a couple inches deep, then it could be a problem.